# Security on azure Cosmos db

Tags: security, encryption, ssl-certificate, azure-cosmosdb

I want to use Cosmos db with c# code. A really important point is that data should stay encrypted at any point. So, as I understood, once the data on the server, it's automaticaly encrypted by azure by the encryption-at-rest. But during the transportation, do I have to use certificate or it's automatically encrypted. I used this link to manage the database https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-dotnet. My question is finally : Is there any risk of safety if I just follow this tutorial?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a great starting point.

Just one note, your data is only as secure as the access keys to the account so, on top encryption at rest and in transit, the Access Key is probably the most sensitive piece of information you need to protect.

My advice is to use a KeyVault to store the database access key rather than define them as environment variables. Combined with Managed Identity, your key will never leave the confines of the azure portal which makes it the most secure option. I'm not sure how you plan on deploying your code but more times than not I've seen those keys encoded in source code or in some configuration file that ends up exposed.

A while ago I wrote a step-by-step tutorial describing how to implement this. You can find my article [here](https://alexdrenea.com/2018/10/23/securing-cosmosdb-keys-with-azure-keyvault/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow the instructions mentioned in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/quickstart-dotnet?tabs=azure-portal%2Cwindows%2Cpasswordless%2Csign-in-azure-cli#create-the-custom-role), and not even using access keys, because if they are accidentally exposed, no matter that you have stored them in a Key Vault or not, your database is out there. Besides, if you want to use access keys, it is recommended to change the access keys periodically, which then you need to make this automatic and known to your key vault, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/tutorial-rotation-dual?tabs=azure-cli) it is described how you could automate that.